# How to show dialog box once in a three days in application

Tags: java, android, dialog, sharedpreferences

Here is my code it is working please tell me code button for "no thanks" if user tap on this button then dialog box never show at all

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Button btnRegId;
    EditText etRegId;
    String regID;

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    String regid,url;

    //String PROJECT_NUMBER = "90787073097";
    String PROJECT_NUMBER =  "440085976573";


    String android_id,version,ver;


ImageView mega4,todayTips,latstnews,sportquiz,tipister;

TextView txtname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // etRegId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtvID);




    //********************For Rating APP **********************
     SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("RATER", 0);

     SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();

    long time = sharedPrefs.getLong("displayedTime", 0);
    if (time < System.currentTimeMillis() - 259200000) {
       displayDialog();
       prefsEditor.putLong("displayedTime", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
    }
 }

   //dialog box Function for rating app.

private void displayDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                //Yes button clicked
                   Intent in = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                   in.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                   startActivity(in);
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Rate This App");
    builder.setMessage("You really seem to like this app, "
              +"since you have already used it %totalLaunchCount% times! "
              +"It would be great if you took a moment to rate it.")
    .setPositiveButton("Rate Now", dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton("Latter", dialogClickListener)
        .setNeutralButton("No,thanks", dialogClickListener).show();

   }
   //End dialog box Function for rating app.
  }
```

Here is my code actually i want to implement app rating dialog box in application that should display once in three day

Comment: share your logcat

Comment: Whats the flow, from where you are calling this logic? Background or main thread? and what you write in displayDialog

Comment: Probably crash in displayDialog function. Pls add your Logcat and displayDialog Method code

Comment: Do you want to show the dialog box only when user is in the app or even when the app is closed?

Comment: user in the app @AayushThakur

Comment: It is updated now please check it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize your SharedPreferences and Editor Object like this:

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("RATER", 0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

**UPDATE**

Just save a boolean when user cliks on no thanks and check it before showing the dialog. If it true then it will not show the dialog box.

```
//Saving a boolean on no thanks button click

SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("RATER", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("NO THANKS", true));
editor.apply();
```

Access it in your dialog showing method.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("RATER", 0);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("NO THANKS", false)) {
        return;
    }else {
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    //YOUR CODE TO SHOW DIALOG
    editor.apply();
}
```

**FULL CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnRegId;
EditText etRegId;
String regID;

GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
String regid, url;

//String PROJECT_NUMBER = "90787073097";
String PROJECT_NUMBER = "440085976573";


String android_id, version, ver;


ImageView mega4, todayTips, latstnews, sportquiz, tipister;

TextView txtname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // etRegId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtvID);


    //********************For Rating APP **********************
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("RATER", 0);
    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NO THANKS", false)) {
        return;
    } else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        //YOUR CODE TO SHOW DIALOG
        long time = sharedPrefs.getLong("displayedTime", 0);
        if (time < System.currentTimeMillis() - 259200000) {
            displayDialog();
            prefsEditor.putLong("displayedTime", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
        }
        prefsEditor.apply();
    }


}

//dialog box Function for rating app.

private void displayDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes button clicked
                    Intent in = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    in.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(in);
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    //Saving a boolean on no thanks button click

                    SharedPreferences prefs = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("RATER", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("NO THANKS", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Rate This App");
    builder.setMessage("You really seem to like this app, "
            + "since you have already used it %totalLaunchCount% times! "
            + "It would be great if you took a moment to rate it.")
            .setPositiveButton("Rate Now", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Latter", dialogClickListener)
            .setNeutralButton("No,thanks", dialogClickListener).show();

}
//End dialog box Function for rating app.
    }
```

Comment: mContext mean will replaced by  "MainActivity.this"?

Comment: Yes, if it is activity you can also use this.getSharedPreferences

Comment: ok good, please write me some code when user tap on "no thanks" button there should be never again show dialog box at all

Comment: pls write me proper code i cannot understand, where i write this code? also attach with my code for better understanding to me thanks , i am accepted you answer @aayush

Answer (score 4):

here is my code as a function for 10 days. 
I made the initial value current time - 11 days to make sure it will run first time app launches

```
  public void dialogEvery10Days() {
  Long duration = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getLong("duration", System.currentTimeMillis()-TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(11));
      if (System.currentTimeMillis()-duration > TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(10)) {
            // inflateDialog is a function containing the functionality of popping up the dialog
            Dialog dialog = inflateDialog(R.layout.dialog_layout);

            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit()
                    .putLong("duration", System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .apply();
        }
    }
```